# How to detect right-click on a TMenuItem with WM_MENURBUTTONUP?

Tags: delphi, winapi, menuitem, delphi-11-alexandria

In a 32-bit Delphi 11 VCL Application on Windows 10, I use a `TApplicationEvents` component to catch Windows Messages. Unfortunately, `TApplicationEvents` seems to not react to the `WM_MENURBUTTONUP` message when I RIGHT-CLICK on a `TPopupMenu` MenuItem:

```
procedure TForm1.ApplicationEvents1Message(var Msg: tagMSG; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  case Msg.message of
      Winapi.Messages.WM_MENURBUTTONUP: CodeSite.Send('TForm1.ApplicationEvents1Message: WM_MENURBUTTONUP');
  end;
end;
```

The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-menurbuttonup) says:

> WM_MENURBUTTONUP message
> Sent when the user releases the right mouse button while the cursor is on a menu item.

As an alternative, `WM_COMMAND` is sent with BOTH Left- and Right-Clicks. However, for a specific purpose, I need to react only when RIGHT-Clicking a menu item.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quoted part of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-menurbuttonup) explains why you aren't seeing this message:

> **Sent** when the user [...]

The [`TApplicationEvents.OnMessage`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.OnMessage) event is only able to detect *posted* messages, not *sent* messages.

## TMainMenu

So if you want to detect this message, you can add

```pascal
  protected
    procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;
```

to your form class, implemented as follows:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  if Message.Msg = WM_MENURBUTTONUP then
    ShowMessage('rbu')
  else
    inherited
end;
```

Try, for instance:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  if Message.Msg = WM_MENURBUTTONUP then
  begin
    var MI := Menu.FindItem(Message.LParam, fkHandle);
    if Assigned(MI) and InRange(Message.WParam, 0, MI.Count - 1) then
      ShowMessageFmt('Menu item "%s" right clicked.', [MI.Items[Message.WParam].Caption]);
  end
  else
    inherited
end;
```

## TPopupMenu

For a `TPopupMenu`, you need to write your own `TPopupList` descendant:

```pascal
type
  TPopupListEx = class(TPopupList)
  protected
    procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;
  end;

{ TPopupListEx }

procedure TPopupListEx.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  if Message.Msg = WM_MENURBUTTONUP then
    ShowMessage('rbu')
  else
    inherited
end;

initialization
  FreeAndNil(PopupList);
  PopupList := TPopupListEx.Create;
```

And make sure to set the `TPopupMenu`'s `TrackButton` to `tbLeftButton`.

If you have several popup menus, you might try something like this (not fully tested):

```pascal
procedure TPopupListEx.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  if Message.Msg = WM_MENURBUTTONUP then
  begin
    for var X in PopupList do
      if TObject(X) is TPopupMenu then
      begin
        OutputDebugString(PChar(TPopupMenu(X).Name));
        var MI: TMenuItem;
        if TPopupMenu(X).Handle = HMENU(Message.LParam) then
          MI := TPopupMenu(X).Items
        else
          MI := TPopupMenu(X).FindItem(HMENU(Message.LParam), fkHandle);
        if Assigned(MI) and InRange(Message.WParam, 0, MI.Count - 1) then
        begin
          ShowMessageFmt('Menu item "%s" right clicked.', [MI.Items[Message.WParam].Caption]);
          Break;
        end;
      end;
  end
  else
    inherited
end;
```

[image: Screen recording of example application showing RMB clicks in the main menu and two different context menus.]

Comment: Nice code! It works with `TMainMenu`, but unfortunately, it does not work with `TPopupMenu`.

Comment: @user1580348: Correct. For that I suspect you need to make your own `TPopupList` descendant.

Comment: I understand. Do you know whether it is possible to get the state of modifier keys inside a `TApplicationEvents.OnMessage` event-handler?

Comment: @user1580348: I added that approach to my answer, so now it works with popup menus. Yes, certainly it is possible. Use `GetKeyState`.